# Cron job does not trigger Airflow DAG externally

Tags: cron, airflow

I am quite new to Airflow. However, I bumped into the same timing and interval issues that novice faced when dealing with the schedule interval. As such I wanted to try to externally trigger a DAG via cli. This can be done by simply going to the console and typing example:
`airflow trigger_dag tutorial`
(using airflow docker image: 1.10.9)

Next I wanted to see if the same command works with a regular cron job as I wanted to trigger it as like a cron job time. Hence I created a cron job of something like this:
`* * * * * airflow trigger_dag tutorial`

However this does not trigger the DAG now.
Upon other few experiments, I can manually trigger the DAG via the same command in an shell script, but it cannot be done with a sh command via the cron job.
(I have verified that the cron works as I tried with just outputing a normal file.)

Can anybody tell me how I can trigger the DAG with a regular cron job?
Or what went wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have some environment variable in your user's profile - possibly also .bash_profile or .bashrc that are not available in cron. Cron does not "source" any of the user profile files - you need to source them manually if you want to set them, before running the script.

Nice article that also shows you how to debug it is here: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/cron-environment-and-cron-job-failures

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the cron command with full path to Airflow. To get installation path you can execute:

`which airflow`

Now update the cron command.